# Elasticsearch query match + term boolean

Tags: elasticsearch

I have documents in elasticsearch index with a "type" field, like this:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "serviceDescription": "a bunch of text",
    "serviceTitle": "title",
    "serviceTags":["tag1","tag2"]
    "type":"service"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "companyDescription": "a bunch of text more",
    "companyTitle": "title",
    "companyTags":["tag1","tag2"]
    "type":"company"
  },...
]
```

I want to run a match query across all docs in my index, like this:

```
body = {
    "query": {
        "match": {
            "_all":"sequencing"
        }
    }
}
```

but add a filter to only return results where the "type" field equals "service".

Comment: do you want to search for `sequencing` query string across all the fields of documents? Can you please explain **add a filter to only return results where the "type" field equals "service".**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can understand your question, you want to query for `sequencing` query string, across all the fields, for that
you can use the [multi_match query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html) that builds on the match query to allow multi-field queries.

> If no fields are provided, the multi_match query defaults to the
> index.query.default_field index settings, which in turn defaults to *.
> This extracts all fields in the mapping that are eligible to term queries and filters the metadata fields. All extracted fields are then
> combined to build a query.

**Search Query:**

```
    {
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "multi_match": {
            "query": "bunch of text"
          }
        }
      ],
      "filter": {
        "term": {
          "type": "service"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "64867032",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 0.8630463,
        "_source": {
          "id": 1,
          "serviceDescription": "a bunch of text",
          "serviceTitle": "title",
          "serviceTags": [
            "tag1",
            "tag2"
          ],
          "type": "service"
        }
      }
    ]
```

Comment: @Brian Guan did you get a chance to go through my answer, looking forward to get feedback from you :)

Comment: no, I want to search across all fields, but then only return fields were the "type" field value is equal to something

Comment: so in the two docs i provided, one has type: service, one has type: company. I want to add a filter to only return type: service, so ex: query: "bunch of text", only return the first doc.

Comment: @BrianGuan please go through my updated answer, and let me know if this resolves your issue ?

Comment: @BrianGuan it's been a long time. I hope you are doing well  Did you get a chance to go through my answer, looking forward to get feedback from you :) And if my answer helped you resolve your issue then please don't forget to upvote and accept the answer 